# Checkbox doesn't display as checked

Tags: wordpress, css, layout, checkbox

**Edit 2016-11-02:** The :checked state isn't possible to modify through this plug-in according to the developer. But I bought some custom coding and the feature to upload images for unchecked / hover / checked will be implemented. :) The plug-in is Zigaform, if anyone in the future would look for some similar solution.

---

Original post:

The checkboxes don't display as checked, after I've modified their appearances with CSS. The checkboxes do check though, since the values collect in the summary of the form. So it's just a matter of CSS I believe. Moreover, unchecked and hover states work(!), which makes it weirder to me.

Here's a snippet of the HTML code, which I tried to strip down as best as I could. I'm not a coder, so I'm using a 3rd party plug-in with Wordpress which generates lots of code. Let me know if there's something essential missing.

```
<div id="rockfm_ui3brbw6kci" data-idfield="ui3brbw6kci" data-typefield="41" class="rockfm-dyncheckbox rockfm-field rockfm-costest-field ">
  <div class="rockfm-input-container">
    <div data-gal-id="blueimp-gallery5" data-opt-label="Option 1" title="Option 1" class="uifm-dcheckbox-item">
      <div class="uifm-dcheckbox-item-wrap">
        <div class="uifm-dcheckbox-item-chkst btn-default"> </div>
        <div style="display:none" class="uifm-dcheckbox-item-qty-wrap">
          <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-btn"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" > </button>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn"> </span> <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> </button>
          </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="uifm-dcheckbox-item-chkval" name="uiform_fields[ui3brbw6kci][0]" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked"> </div>
      <div class="uifm-dcheckbox-item-gal-imgs">
      </div>
    </div>
    <canvas class="uifm-dcheckbox-item-viewport"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS modifications:

```
.uifm-dcheckbox-item-viewport {
  margin: -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.uifm-dcheckbox-item-viewport:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
  filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}

.uifm-dcheckbox-item-viewport input:checked {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

Probably it has something to do with **:checked**. I know this is possible with CSS3 only, since the code works by itself. Likely I've just missed something obvious.

Regards,

Comment: Is there any way you can boil this down a bit to the essentials? There's a LOT of extra code here when the question is just about a checkbox and its styling. It'll make it much more likely to receive an answer if you don't force folks to parse 200 lines of code.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's just that I might strip out some essentials, since I'm not sure what everything means. But I'll try at least and report back.

Comment: Ok, now I've stripped down.

Comment: Your code has a few surplus closing `</div>` tags, and a typo - as pointed out by gi05 in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40328344/82548) - which leaves a `<button>`'s opening tag unclosed (the third line in your posted HTML). Please correct that, and remove anything surplus to the question (I can't, for example, see any reason to retain the `<a>`, or the `<img>`, elements in your code). I realise this may be perceived as unwelcome pestering, but the more you can do to help us to help you, the more useful the eventual answers will - hopefully - be for you (and future visitors).

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Hopefully I'm not getting anyone frustrated, I'm doing my best for everyone's sake of course. Either way, code updated and I've replied to gi05 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css. Now it should work. You can customize the filter as desired.

```
.uifm-dcheckbox-item-chkst.btn-default.uifm-dcheckbox-checked ~ canvas {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
    -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
    filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I accidentally stripped that out. The thing is that it's a 3rd party plug-in which automatically renders the code and I'm not sure which class is defining which element to a detailed level. But since the unchecked and hover states work, I still suspect there's something wrong with the CSS. Either way, I've updated the HTML (and stripped once again since it's A LOT of code) and feel free to take a 2nd look.

Comment: All right, I saw you attached the code again, although I couldn't see any changes made? The CSS code is the only thing I'm able to modify. The checkboxes are indeed working fine, except the :checked state doesn't stick once checked. This is the testing-page btw: http://www.mixningskonsulten.com/zigaform-test2/

Comment: Ok, is it correct, that when i click for example the checkboxes 1 and 6-15 you want that the selectet checkboxes gets blue and stay till you click again? Like in the picture here http://pasteboard.co/lCUttZsYv.png

Comment: Currently the CSS modification are supposed to display the checkboxes "more blue" once checked - like the image here: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/akwt1j/9. But yes, you seem to understand what I'm trying to achieve. :) As you can see, the form and the CSS is working as it should otherwise so that's why I think it must have something to do with only the line :checked in the CSS code.. Then again, coding is not my expertise.

Comment: Oh, and to further explain a bit: Checked = No modification, just the image as it is originally.